# Generalized Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, smooth domain, then the Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequalites (inter alia) state

$$\|\nabla v\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \le C \|D^2 v\|_{L^r(\Omega)}^a \|v\|_{L^q(\Omega)}^{1-a} + \|v\|_{L^s(\Omega)}$$

for certain values of $p, r, q, s$ and $a$ (and $C$ only depending on these values an $\Omega$).

Question: Is there also an inequality of the type

$$\|\nabla v\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \le C \|D^2 v\|_{L^{r_1}(\Omega)}^{a_1} \|\nabla v\|_{L^{r_2}(\Omega)}^{a_2} \|v\|_{L^q(\Omega)}^{1-a_1-a_2} + \|v\|_{L^s(\Omega)}$$

(where for example $a_1$ may be chosen smaller than $a$ in the first inequality, provided $a_2 \gt 0$, $r=r_1$ and $p, q, s$ remain the same)?

PS: The title might be misleading, but I was unable to come up with a better wording of my question; sorry. (This is also the reason I had problems googling this question)